# How do I get anisotropy to work in 2.72?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

I must be doing something wrong here, but for some reason in blender 2.72/2.72b the anisotropy shader is acting no different from a glossy shader.

Here is a comparison:
[image]

As you can see, there is no difference.  I have tried all distributions and tangents and adjusting the rotation to no avail.

Here are my nodes:  [image]

I have not used any anisotropy since 2.72 came out and just opened up a simple scene I have not worked on for a while and noticed that none of the anisotropy is working as before.
Here is the scene I noticed it on:
[image]
The second render is the one I want.

Is anisotropy done differently in 2.72, or is this a bug?  I am inclined to think this is not a bug since somebody should have reported it by now, and one of the new things in 2.72 is the new Ashikhmin-Shirley distribution.

Comment: For the anisotropy to be noticeable, there has to be some roughness. Is it possible you could upload before/after renders of the file which broke in 2.72? Or the .blend in question?

Comment: @gandalf3 I added the renders of the scene I noticed it on, rendered on 2.71 and 2.72.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Anisotropic material no longer appears radial?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18271/anisotropic-material-no-longer-appears-radial)

Comment: It looks like the tangent is set differently

Comment: @gandalf3 the two renders are of the *exact same scene* the tangent is the same (radial Z) in both.  Roughness is 0.25.

Comment: That's very strange. Sounds like a bug to me.. Is it possible you could upload a .blend of just the anisotropic object?

Comment: @gandalf3 [Here](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/32892) is the .blend file of the pot.

Comment: There seems to be something odd about the beckmann distribution when used with the anisotropic shader. In 2.71 the anisotropic shader didn't have a distribution option, but it looks like it used *ward* which has since been removed in favor of the newer distributions. Not sure the the strangeness with beckmann is a bug or not..

Comment: Actually I'm quite sure this is a bug, and it's still here in the latest version I have readily available for testing (`fb820c0`). I don't see it reported anywhere after a quick search, which could be understandable given that the default distribution is GGX. Would you like to report it? If not, let me know and I can do it :)

Comment: @NoviceInDisguiseGraphics the point is that the 2.72 render is showing no anisotropy, even though it has an anisotropic shader with a very high anisotropy value.

Comment: @PGmath The reason there is no anisotropy in the first examples seems to be due to the lack of any roughness. The lack of anisotropy in the 2.72 pot render seems due to an unrelated bug with the beckmann distribution.

Comment: @gandalf3 I did not realize that anisotropy requires roughness, it makes perfect sense now that I think about it though.  So if you add that as an answer I will be happy to accept it :).  I will report the bug soon, I have several on my list.  Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need some roughness for the anisotropy to be visible.

[image]

As I understand it, anisotropic shading simulates the way light reflects off objects with fine grooves like on CD/DVDs or machined cylindrical objects. Without any roughness, the surface is considered smooth (no grooves).

Answer (score 1):

I found the same problem - anisotropic shaders, didn't work with Blender 2.73 on a project which I started on Blender 2.71. There is some kind of a mismatch whit Blender versions. Shaders worked properly when I deleted anisotropic nodes and added them again.