# Cycles: Adding / Installing a Downloaded Material made for blender internal

Tags: materials

I just downloaded an aluminum material and saved it to my desktop.

http://matrep.parastudios.de/index.php?action=view&material=655-brushed-aluminum

I tried installing it by opening the object I wanted to apply it too and went to File > Append > Material and Clicked Append from Library... But.. Hmmm. But now what? I don't see a Library button to find the new aluminum material. How do I get that onto my object? Did I not install it right?

Thanks in advance.
Marc

Comment: It should be present in the materials dropdown. Make sure you are using the same render engine

Comment: Nuts... the tutorial i was going by has me working in Cycles Render, to where I already applied node materials to some objects... but it looks like the aluminum i downloaded was made with Blender render.  So that means I can't use it huh?

Comment: No, sadly the materials are extremely different between the two render engines

Comment: Ok.. Cool. Thanks for your time. For anyone that comes across this thread and needs an excellent brushed metal / stainless material please check this guy's tutorial out! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ECf5wIKB_5g

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6446/is-there-a-way-to-have-one-material-for-cycles-and-the-bi

Comment: recreating that aluminum  material in cycles is quite easy using an anisotropic shader. http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/9336/1853 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18905/how-do-i-get-anisotropy-to-work-in-2-72/26086#26086

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise can you add your comment as an answer?

Comment: @cegaton Sure, I'll do that today