# Strange lines appearing when render Anisotropic BSDF

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, materials

I'm trying to render a steel plate with the *Anistoropic BSDF*. I would like to have curved reflections as it happens in pans or pots (for cooking). Instead, when I render, I get this strange straight lines appearing on the plate surface, and I cannot get rid of them. As a source light I'm using two planes with emmision. Here are images of the case (with the plate nodes) and of the rendered image. I don't know it this can help, but it was created with FreeCAD. May be it can be related with the problem.

Here is the link to the blender file

[image]

Thanks all for you help.

David

[image: case and nodes]

[image: rendered image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the final fixed result:

[image]

### Shading

You need to click on the *Tangent* menu in the material settings and select a *Tangent* node. Make sure *Radial* is selected it its settings. Play around with the *Axes:* to figure out which one to use.

[image]

*Gandalf3's image from [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18271/anisotropic-material-no-longer-appears-radial).*

### Modeling

Your mesh is covered in triangles (not good). From the .blend file that I downloaded, this was my process:

1. <kbd>A</kbd> twice to select everything.
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> converts many tris to quads.
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, then <kbd>3</kbd> to enter *Face Select Mode*.
4. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> while hovering over one of the edges around the outside rim to select this face loop:

[image]

5. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to *Invert Selection*.
6. <kbd>X</kbd> > *Faces* to open the *Delete* menu and delete *Faces*.
7. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, then <kbd>1</kbd> to enter *Vertex Select Mode*.
8. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> while hovering over one of the edges in the topmost edge loop to select this edge loop:

[image]

9. <kbd>F</kbd> to create an *N-Gon* face.
10. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to *Invert Selection*.
11. <kbd>F</kbd> to create an *N-Gon* face.
12. <kbd>Tab</kbd> out of *Edit Mode*.

Here is the fixed .blend file:

[image]

P.S.

This is not included in the .blend file, but if you want less spotty anisotropy, you should use these settings in the *Properties panel > Render tab*.

[image]

They produce this result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply Shady Puck, I tried what you said and effectively reflections seem to be radial. However the strange lines still are there. I noticed that smoothing the nodes the lines vary, so I guess they are related with the elements. However I still dont know how to solve the problem.

Comment: @DavidS. Can you upload your .blend file to [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com) and edit your question with the provided link?

Comment: @DavidS. See my edit. If this answer helped you, please consider marking it as accepted by selecting the checkmark in its upper, left-hand corner. It would help me greatly and make me very happy!