# photorealistic scratched Brushed alluminium

Tags: materials

I want to do a brushed alluminium piece (quite like a cylinder with little rounded corners) but the brushing is radial on the top and then linear on the sides. Making two textures is inconvenient and not seamless.

How I can do this with tha material nodes?

(I thought about 2 displacement maps but I couldn't make the thing work)

heres is a (blurry) photo of what I exactly want
[image: heres is a (blurry) photo of what I exactly want]

Here Is What I Currently Have
[image: Here Is What I Currently Have]

Comment: Have you tried messing with the anisotropic shader?

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/110767/anisotropic-bsdf-on-multiple-meshes/110779#110779

Comment: Yeah I'mUsing the Annisotropic shader but the material isnt scored

Comment: In addition to the anisotropic shader you need a Tangent Node (shift + "A" > Input > Tangent).

Comment: I allready did that But men you Brush alluminium you score it and that create the anisotropic effect but the actual piece is scored in circles or in lines depending on how you did it and I know how to apply a Displacement map But in this case I will have to apply 2 of them and I don't know how to do it (Maybe with math nodes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK i found the answer so I post this for other people:
I used only one bump map and I just streched the texture over the cylinder

(I used This texture https://www.poliigon.com/texture/metal-radial-001)

Here is the Uv map

[image: Uv map]

here are the nodes

[image]

here is the result

[image]